# Unhandled error LateInitializationError: Field 'currentUser' has not been initialized. occurred in Instance of 'HomeBloc'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

so i do get this error : Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error LateInitializationError: Field 'currentUser' has not been initialized. occurred in Instance of 'HomeBloc'.

> E/flutter (11536): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error LateInitializationError: Field
> 'currentUser' has not been initialized. occurred in Instance of
> 'HomeBloc'. E/flutter (11536): #0      GlobalConstants.currentUser
> (package:fitness_flutter/core/const/global_constants.dart) E/flutter
> (11536): #1      DataService.getWorkoutsForUser
> (package:fitness_flutter/core/service/data_service.dart:9:43)
> E/flutter (11536): #2      HomeBloc.mapEventToState
> (package:fitness_flutter/screens/home/bloc/home_bloc.dart:27:36)
> E/flutter (11536):

Line 9 from data_service.dart : `final currUserEmail = GlobalConstants.currentUser.mail;`

Line 27 from home_bloc.dart :  `workouts = await DataService.getWorkoutsForUser();`

This is my data_service.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:fitness_flutter/core/const/global_constants.dart';
import 'package:fitness_flutter/core/service/user_storage_service.dart';
import 'package:fitness_flutter/data/workout_data.dart';

class DataService {
  static Future<List<WorkoutData>> getWorkoutsForUser() async {
    final currUserEmail = GlobalConstants.currentUser.mail;

    // await UserStorageService.deleteSecureData('${currUserEmail}Workouts');

    final workoutsStr =
        await UserStorageService.readSecureData('${currUserEmail}Workouts');
    if (workoutsStr == null) return [];
    final decoded = (json.decode(workoutsStr) as List?) ?? [];
    final workouts = decoded.map((e) {
      final decodedE = json.decode(e) as Map<String, dynamic>?;
      return WorkoutData.fromJson(decodedE!);
    }).toList();
    GlobalConstants.workouts = workouts;
    return workouts;
  }

  static Future<void> saveWorkout(WorkoutData workout) async {
    final allWorkouts = await getWorkoutsForUser();
    final index = allWorkouts.indexWhere((w) => w.id == workout.id);
    if (index != -1) {
      allWorkouts[index] = workout;
    } else {
      allWorkouts.add(workout);
    }
    GlobalConstants.workouts = allWorkouts;
    final workoutsStr = allWorkouts.map((e) => e.toJsonString()).toList();
    final encoded = json.encode(workoutsStr);
    final currUserEmail = GlobalConstants.currentUser.mail;
    await UserStorageService.writeSecureData(
      '${currUserEmail}Workouts',
      encoded,
    );
  }
}
```

This is my global_constants.dart :

```
import 'package:fitness_flutter/data/user_data.dart';
import 'package:fitness_flutter/data/workout_data.dart';

class GlobalConstants {
  static late UserData currentUser;
  static late List<WorkoutData> workouts;
}
```

This is my home_bloc.dart

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  HomeBloc() : super(HomeInitial());

  List<WorkoutData> workouts = <WorkoutData>[];
  List<ExerciseData> exercises = <ExerciseData>[];
  int timeSent = 0;

  @override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(
    HomeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is HomeInitialEvent) {
      workouts = await DataService.getWorkoutsForUser();
      yield WorkoutsGotState(workouts: workouts);
    } else if (event is ReloadImageEvent) {
      String? photoURL = await UserStorageService.readSecureData('image');
      if (photoURL == null) {
        photoURL = AuthService.auth.currentUser?.photoURL;
        photoURL != null
            ? await UserStorageService.writeSecureData('image', photoURL)
            : print('no image');
      }
      yield ReloadImageState(photoURL: photoURL);
    } else if (event is ReloadDisplayNameEvent) {
      final displayName = await UserStorageService.readSecureData('name');
      yield ReloadDisplayNameState(displayName: displayName);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because leading up to the line where you were trying to access `currentUser`, there was no where you set a value for it, unlike that for `workouts`. You can fix this by particular error by treating is as nullable if you expect it that way, or you initialize it with some value in that line or some other way.

Comment: Could you please help me resolve this problem ?

Comment: Don't know about your code that much. You need to set a value for the `currentUser` property. It's not set now, so you can't use it and because it's lazily initialized, that's why you have the error. You'll need to look into how you set that property before you can call it